# SELinux policy to authorize some users to start / stop certain services

Tags: fedora, selinux, authorization

How can I give certain users authorization to start and stop certain services?
I am asking specifically about Fedora 19 systems with SELinux installed.

The utility to call for services administration is in this case `systemctl`.
What type of SELinux security policy do I have to write? Where? How? Any references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RHEL doesn't yet have systemd, so the approach for Fedora 19 and RHEL will be dramatically different.

At any rate, what you are trying to do is not sanely possible. You'd have to create a separate login role for each user and grant it ability to execute systemd without transitioning into systemd domain -- at which point you'd have to pretty much clone the entire systemd policy into each user's domain and then write another policy for executing each service. Per user. Unless you already have a really awesome understanding of SELinux and are already really excellent at writing SELinux policies (and really love M4), I strongly suggest not going down this route.

Just add sudo rules per user to allow executing things like "/sbin/service foo restart" or "/bin/systemctl restart foo.service". If you want to add SELinux into the fray, make these users staff_u and the rest user_u.

Comment: exactly what I wanted to know! thanks a lot for your guidance, master mricon!!